# Caching with ignite in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, caching, ignite

Just wanted to implement caching using Ignite in springboot with JPA repository  is it possible ?
No reference or examples were found online . can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

How about the Spring Data Repository Support for Apache Ignite?

https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/spring-data

Comment: its good ... it doesnt work in spring boot ..... i followed the document and i am getting an exception saying a instance of ignite with same has already started when i register config class with  context  and if i dont register it the node starts ....but exception occurs saying no qualifying bean for repository

Comment: I think it can be eventually be made to work, also we plan to introduce Spring Boot support soon. You can check it now, see if it works for you: https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/r1556ca389a434d8dfbfb66dcb8598576b2061e8b50c161dee793600c%40%3Cdev.ignite.apache.org%3E